# Angular http.get charset

Tags: angularjs, character-encoding

I'm having some trouble getting my angular application to parse my json-data correctly.

When my json-feed contains e.g. { "title": "Halldórsson Pourié" }
my application shows Halld�rsson Pouri�

I figure the problem is the charset, but i can't find where to change it.

Currently i am using ng-bind-html and using $sce.trustAsHtml(), and I'm very sure the problem occurs when **$http.get(url)** parses my json.

So how do i tell **$http.get(url)** to parse the data with a specific charset?

Comment: Here's a simple plunk, http://plnkr.co/edit/R4pzNAmWguMXcnkClyMX?p=preview, I wasn't able to replicate the issue. Could you take a shot at replicating it?

Comment: I just tried to put my data-source in your plunkr, and the problem occurs again.
When I checked the data-source I used my browser, that probably don't see the data the way angular does. So now I found that the data-source are missing some charsets/encoding data, for angular to encode it properly.
Thanks for you help.

Comment: The plnkr is worthless since the issue is in the connection between the server and the client. Check the edit to my answer.

Comment: By the way, I'm not sure your controller code is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and resolved it by using:

```
 encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(p_Query))
```

where `p_Query` is a JSON containing the details of the request (i.e. your `{ "title": "Halldórsson Pourié" }`).

EDIT:

You may also need to add to the header of your GET request the following:

```
 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded ; charset=UTF-8'
```

Comment: My explanation of the problem might be a bit insufficient. 
I get my data with from a json-feed outside the application. To get the data i use angular $http-service.
But the $http-service automatically parses the json data, and uses UTF-8 (i guess) which does not contains the special characters i need. So when I get to manipulate the data, my special characters has already been converted to �.

Comment: @OngoBoingo, first of all, UTF-8 contains all character sets you may imagine, certainly all you need for French (if I got correctly the language of your example). Secondly, are you saying that the JSON is being delivered towards your Web application? In such case, please define what you have at the server side, who is building the JSON and who is responding to the GET request.

Answer (score 1):

Had same problem with accented characters and some scientific notation in text/JSON fields and found that AngularJS (or whatever native JavaScript XHR/fetch functions it is using) was flattening everything to UTF-8 no matter what else we tried.

The other respondent here claimed that UTF-8 should somehow still be accommodating your extended character set, but we found otherwise: taking samples of the source data directly, we loaded it into text editor with different encodings and UTF-8 would still squash extended characters to that � placeholder.

In our case, the encoding was ISO-8859-15 but you may be sufficient with ISO-8859-1.

Try adding this $http configuration to your $http.get() call, accordingly:

```
$http.get(url, {
    responseType: 'arraybuffer',
    transformResponse: function(data) {
        let textDecoder = new TextDecoder('ISO-8859-15'); // your encoding may vary!
        return JSON.parse(textDecoder.decode(data));
    }
});
```

This should intercept AngularJS default response transformation and instead apply the function here. You will, of course, want to consider adding some error handling, etc.

If there are better ways to do this without a custom transformResponse function, I have yet to find anything in the AngularJS documentation.

Answer (score 1):

`$http.get(url, {responseType: 'arraybuffer', }).then(function (response) {                     var textDecoder = new TextDecoder('ISO-8859-1'); console.log(textDecoder.decode(response.data));});`
This code will replace all your � placeholders into normal characters.